# Pendulum without friction: Are there any relative equilibria?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Hopefully, my question is not too silly.

I am wondering if for the 2D-mathematical pendulum without friction, we do have any *relative equilibrium*: Of course, we have two equilibria (at $(0,0)$ and at $(\pi,0)$ in the $\theta-\dot{\theta}$-plane). But are there any *relative equilibria*?

(As far as I did understand the definition of a [relative equilibrium](http://oldwww.ma.man.ac.uk/~jm/notes/jm-peyresq98.pdf), this is a (symmetry) group orbit which does not change under the dynamics. For the pendulum here, I would say that the symmetry group is the rotation around $2\pi$. Up to my understanding, the only group orbits which does not change then are the orbits

$$
\left\{(0+2\pi k,0): k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2\text{ and }\left\{(\pi+2\pi k,0): k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2
$$ 
in the $\theta$-$\dot{\theta}$-plane.

Hence I would claim that these are (the only) two relative equilibria.)

Comment: There's also the reflection symmetry $\theta\to-\theta$.

Comment: @Semiclassical You are right. But this gives the same two relative equilibria, doesn't it?

Comment: Not sure. Some physics, though: A _driven_ pendulum can have equilibria other than at 0 and $\pi$. The textbook example of this is a bead sliding on a turning vertical hoop; you can find details on this example without too much searching.

Comment: @Semiclassical I am using the equation $\ddot{\theta}(t)+r\dot{\theta}(t)+\sin(\theta(t))=0$ with $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$. This equation (resp. the 2D-system belonging to it) only has the two equilibria $(0,0), (\pi,0)$. What equation do you mean with *driven pendulum*?

Comment: 1) A term like $r\dot{\theta}$ serves as a damping force on a pendulum, and is absent in the standard mathematical pendulum. 2) For the equation of motion in the case of a bead on a spinning hoop, you end up with $\ddot{\theta}+\sin \theta=\omega^2 \sin2\theta$ (derivation can be found [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/ia-dyn-handout13.pdf), with $g=a=1$ and a slight redefinition of $\omega^2$).